# How to create database in android ?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am currently developing a blood donation app in android. I would like to store the details of the users in database so that other users can browser the details and contact them.I have used the

How can I create a database in android.is it possible to connect to MySQL database.

Comment: If you're talking about a server-side database, then yes you can use MySQL, but you're going to need some sort of an API to connect with it.

Comment: There are lot many tutorials/resources exists on the web, search and implement first yourself, if you face any issue then come back and post it here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is the standard choice for Android, it comes integrated with the SDK and can be setup easily. Take a look at the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) for managing data in Android apps.

Comment: Except this database will live on the device and cannot be "browsed by other users". This answer was accepted of course, so I wonder are the requirements in the question correct.

Comment: True. I responded to the question in the title. Not to the actual question that was hidden in his description. However, his actual question is far too broad, so I really can't be bothered.